# Comparing dates in a dataframe and appending info based on comparison result in R

Tags: r, datetime, tidyverse, lubridate

so I am lost with the following problem:
I have a dataframe, in which one column contains (STARTED) the starting time of a survey, and several others information of the survey schedule of that survey participant (D5 to D10: only the planned survey dates, D17 to D50: planned send-out times of measurement per day). I'd like to create to columns that indicate now which survey day (1-6) and which measurement per day (1-6) this survey corresponds to.
First problem is the format (!)...
STARTED has the format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S, D5 to D10 %d.%m.%Y and D17 to D50 %d.%m.%Y %H:%M.
I tried dmy_hms() from lubridate, parse_date_time(), and simply as.POSIXct(), but I always fail to get STARTED and the D17 to D50 section into a comparable format. Any solutions on this one?

After just separating STARTED into date & time columns, I was able to compare using ifelse() with D5 to D10 and to create the column of day running from 1 to 6.
This might be already more elegant with something like which(), but I was not able to create a vectorized version of this, as which(<<D5:D10>> == STARTED) would need to compare that per row. Does anyone have a solution for this?

And lastly, how on earth can I set up the second column indicating the measurement time? The first and last survey of the is easy, as there are also uniquely labelled, but for the other four ones I would need to compare per day whether the starting time is before the planned survey time of the following survey. I could imagine just checking whether STARTED falls in between two planned survey times just next to each other - as a POSIXct object that might work, if I can parse the different formats.

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

A screenshot from the beginning of the data:
[Screenshot from R data using View()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0wfF.png)

For these first few rows, the intended variable day would need to be c(1,2,1,1,1,2,2) and measurement c(3,2,4,2,1,2,3).

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your other columns are *not* formatted with `%d.%m.%Y`, instead either `%d.%m.%t` (date only) or `%d.%m.%y %H:%M`. Note the change from `%Y` to `%y`.

Try:

```r
as.Date("20.05.22", format = "%d.%m.%y")
# [1] "2022-05-20"
as.POSIXct("20.05.22 06:00", format = "%d.%m.%y %H:%M")
# [1] "2022-05-20 06:00:00 EDT"
```